# Why is this C++ class not equivalent to this template?

Tags: c++, templates

Can somebody explain to me why the following works:

```
template<class T> class MyTemplateClass {
public:
    T * ptr;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyTemplateClass<double[5]> a;
    a.ptr = new double[10][5];
    a.ptr[2][3] = 7;
    printf("%g\n", a.ptr[2][3]);
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    double[5] * ptr;
    // double(*ptr)[5]; // This would work
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyClass a;
    a.ptr = new double[10][5];
    a.ptr[2][3] = 7;
    printf("%g\n", a.ptr[2][3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously there is more to template instantiation than just a textual replacement by the arguments to the template - is there a simple explanation of this magic?

For the latter the compiler (g++ 4.1.2) spits out the following error:

```
test.cxx:13: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
```

Where line 13 is the `double[5] * ptr;` line.

The question is not:

"Why does the MyClass example fail? - because C++ doesn't allow Java style array declarations ;-)".

But is:

"Why does the MyTemplateClass example succeed?"

Comment: Does the compiler spit out any error message?

Comment: I guess there is a typo in your second code. Obviously, "MyClass< double[5] > a" will result in an error, because MyClass doesn't expect a template parameter.

Comment: Yes there was a typo.
And yes the compiler (g++ 4.1.2) spits out an error message:
test.cxx:13: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
Where line 13 is the "double[5] * ptr" line.
The question is not why the MyClass snippet fails, it is why does the MyTemplateClass snippet succeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference lies in the C++ grammar. A simple-declaration is formed like this:

```
declaration-specifier-seq init-declarator-list
```

Where declaration-specifier-seq is a sequence of declaration specifiers:

```
simple-type-specifier: int, bool, unsigned, typedef-name, class-name ...
class-specifiers: class X { ... }
type-qualifier: const, volatile
function-specifier: inline, virtual, ... 
storage-class-specifier: extern, static, ...
typedef
```

You get the idea. And init-declarator-list is a list of declarators with an optional initializer for each:

```
a
*a
a[N]
a()
&a = someObj
```

So a full simple-declaration could look like this, containing 3 declarators:

```
int a, &b = a, c[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Class members have special rules to account for the different context in which they appear, but they are very similar. Now, you can do

```
typedef int A[3];
A *a;
```

Since the first uses the typedef specifier and then simple-type-specifier and then a declarator like "a[N]". The second declaration then uses the typedef-name "A" (simple-type-specifier) and then a declarator like "*a". However, you of course cannot do

```
int[3] * a;
```

Since "int[3]" is not a valid declaration-specifier-seq as shown above.

And now, of course, a template is **not** just like a macro text substitution. A template type parameter of course is treated like any other type-name which is interpreted as just the type it names and can appear where a simple-type-specifier can appear. Some C# folks tend to say C++ templates are "just like macros", but of course they are not :)

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T> MyTemplateClass {
    ...
}
```

is closer to

```
template<class T> MyTemplateClass {
    typedef {actual type} T;
    ...
}
```

than to a simple text substitution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between using a pointer or array of pointers. There is a need to allocate memory for each element of your array before you're going to use it, and yes you have a typo in second example you didn't defined template.